# Java Swing display text and disable a button

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write a Java Swing program:

Instructions

Write the application JFrameDisableButton that instantiates a JFrame that contains a JButton. Modify the JFrameDisableButton program so that the JButton is not disabled until the user has clicked at least eight times. At that point, display a JLabel that indicates “That’s enough!”.

My program does NOT display the "That's enough!" message.  I'm trying to display the Click Count number.  The number is not displaying.  Also, I do not know how to disable the button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JFrameDisableButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    final int SIZE = 180;
    Container con = getContentPane();
    JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
    int count = 0;
    final int MAX = 8;
    final int WIDTH = 200;
    final int HEIGHT = 200;
    JLabel label = new JLabel("That's enough!");
    JLabel initLabel = new JLabel("");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("count: ");
    public JFrameDisableButton()
    {
        super("Disable Button");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(button);
        add(label2);
        add(initLabel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        count++;
        label2.setText("count: " + count);
        if (count >= 8)
        {
            initLabel.setText("That's enough");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrameDisableButton frame = new JFrameDisableButton();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overriding the `actionPerformed()` method of your JFrame, not of your JButton.  See [`JButton#addActionListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) and/or the ["action constructor"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JButton.html#%3Cinit%3E(javax.swing.Action))

Comment: [`JButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) inherits [`AbstractButton::setEnabled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled(boolean))

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the ActionListener interface is not enough.

Swing cant guess what component the ActionListener should be used for.

You need to add the `ActionListener` to your button:

```
button.addActionListener( this );
```

To initially disable the button you use:

```
button.setEnabled( false );
```